# My DC Bot send a message twice or more times

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make a simple welcomer bot, but I ran into an issue, sometimes the bot send a welcome message twice or more times, and I can't figure out why it's happening. Here's my code and a picture of the bug.

Code:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    let welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "új-tagok");
    let welcomer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${member.guild.name}`)
    .setColor("#FF8A00")
    .setThumbnail("https://i.redd.it/f1u2wf28nqn21.jpg")
    .setDescription(`D-${getRandomInt(0, 9)}${getRandomInt(0, 9)}${getRandomInt(0, 9)}${getRandomInt(0, 9)}, más néven ${member.user.username} csatlakozott a szerverre!`);
     welcomeChannel.send(welcomer);
});
```

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1tF6.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you didn't launch the bot twice?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Are you sure that you only have 1 `guildMemberAdd` event listener?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @Xandrrrr

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways that could assist in fixing this issue:

#### Check you have the client started only once

Make sure you don't have two terminals running at once. This also includes certain bot hosting, where both the terminal and the host are running at once.

#### Regenerate the token

While this should be your last result, even though it's not that of a big deal, sometimes bot token regenerating could fix the issue, although as I said, keep it as a last result.

#### Killing the entire process

You can try to completely kill the process by using the `Client.destroy()` function **inside** of your code or pressing `cmd + Z` on your keyboard inside of the terminal.

[image]

#### Finally, just try restarting.

Try restarting either your coding platform or computer as a whole, it could assist sometimes in giving the client a quick refresh and might just do the job. It helped me countless of times in the past.